# Cálculos en una columna de un dataframe dependientes del valor anterior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Intento calcular una nueva columna 'C' en un dataframe cuyo valor depende del valor anterior de esa misma columna.
Por ejemplo: dado el siguiente dataframe:

```
datos = {'A': [10,20,30,40,50] , 'B': [2,4,6,8,10] }
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que el primer valor de la columna 'C' sea 100, y a partir de ahí quiero que el siguiente valor de 'C' sea  igual a al valor anterior de 'C' + valor de A + ( valor de B *10)

He conseguido resolverlo con un bucle:

```
lista = [100]
for i in range(4):
    lista.append( (lista[-1] + (datos['A'][i+1] ) + datos['B'][i+1] * 10))
df['C'] = lista
df
```

Quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera saber si podría resolverlo sin utilizar bucle. Resolverlo con el cálculo vectorial de pandas. Tengo muchas filas y quisiera evitar el bucle.

He intentado el siguiente código, pero me devuelve un NaN en el primer número de la columna 'C'

```
df['C'] = 100
df['C'] = df['C'].shift(1) + df['A'] + df['B'] *10
```

Y también he intentado:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].shift(1) + df['A'] + df['B'] *10
```

Pero me devuelve un error.

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: +1 por la pregunta perfectamente planteada, con un Dataset de ejemplo creado, el resultado esperado, los intentos y lo que se busca conseguir. Este es un ejemplo de lo que es una buena pregunta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo cálculos vectoriales y que se use toda la potencia de Pandas, una solución, siguiendo con tu ejemplo, es esta:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = {'A': [10,20,30,40,50] , 'B': [2,4,6,8,10] }
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

df["C"] = (df["A"] + df["B"] * 10)
df["C"][0] = 100
df["C"] = df["C"].cumsum()

print(df)
```

**Salida:**

```
    A   B   C
0   10  2   100
1   20  4   160
2   30  6   250
3   40  8   370
4   50  10  520
```

### Explicación

1. Creamos la columna *C* con la formula indicada *a+b·10* `(df["A"] + df["B"] * 10)`. **Pandas puede hacer operaciones vectoriales entre columnas**
2. Despues indicamos que el primer dato de la columna *C* debe ser 100. `df["C"][0] = 100`
3. Por último realizamos la suma acumulada con el método `.cumsum()` de la columna *C*. `df["C"] = df["C"].cumsum()`

### Extra

También Pandas tiene otros métodos como `.cumprod()`, `.cummax()`, etc. Te dejo aquí la [documentación oficial de pandas sobre estos métodos](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto.
Ya había explorado lo de usar .cumsum() lo que pasa que cada ciertas columnas tengo que reiniciar el valor de la columna C, y los cálculos con A y B también dependen del valor de C, por lo que no me servía el método .cumsum().
Voy a intentar reformular la pregunta a ver si doy con la solución.
Un Saludo y repito, mucha gracias.

Comment: De nada @JAGOLAS siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)

Comment: Hola @rubialesalberto he editado la pregunta, ¿podrías orientarme? Gracias

Comment: Hola @Rubiales Alberto he editado la pregunta, ¿podrías orientarme? Gracias

Comment: Hola @JAGOLAS las preguntas respondidas correctamente no deben ser editadas, ya que si lo haces, la respuesta pierde sentido y no sirve a la comunidad. Lo correcto es hacer una nueva pregunta con el problema que tengas

Comment: Hola @rubialesalberto, tienes razón, he vuelto a editar la pregunta y la he dejado como estaba. Respondo abajo a mi propia pregunta, planteándola de nuevo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulo mi pregunta anterior puesto que en el ejemplo que ponía no resolvía realmente lo que quería hacer.

Partiendo del siguiente Dataframe con las cotizaciones o precio de cierre de IBM a fin de mes y al que le he añadido una columna donde voy a ir aportando 100€ en cada cuatrimestre (es decir el último día del mes en el que está la inversión):

```
datos = {'IBM': [137.62,124.79,131.03,151.45,145.94,153.74,\
             151.78,160.62,158.88,158.85,153.69,162.22,165.99] }
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, index='dic-15 ene-16 feb-16 mar-16 abr-16 may-16 \
             jun-16 jul-16 ago-16 sep-16 oct-16 nov-16 dic-16'.split())
df['inversión'] = ([100] + [0] *3) * 3 + [0]
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento calcular una nueva columna 'Capital' que me indique el capital que tengo acumulado al final de cada mes.

Lo he conseguido con un bucle:

```
capital = []
for i in range(13):
    if i == 0:
        capital.append(df['inversión'][i])
    else:
        capital.append( (capital[-1] * df['IBM'][i] / df['IBM'][i-1] ) + 
df['inversión'][i])
df['Capital'] = capital
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si se podría hacer con cálculo vectorial en lugar de con bucle.

He intentado:

```
df['Capital2'] = 100  
df['Capital2'] = df['Capital2'] * df['IBM'][i] / df['IBM'].shift(1) + 
df['inversión']
df
```

Pero me devuelve un NnN en la primera fila y el resto de datos no están bien.

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

Muchas Gracias.